# File Upload in Angular catching value but not posting data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, file-upload

I've been trying for days now to upload multiple files in my Angular Application using ngx-material-file-input. I'm using angular reactive forms, no error is coming when logging the data in the console. The key `imagePath` gets a value `[object FileList]` when consoling `formData` after appending the imagePath to it. But for some reason, nothing gets posted actually in the database. Check out my code below for further details. Any sort of assistance is appreciated.

**UPDATE::** it's working if single file upload is done and using the below `onSelectedFile($event)` but still unable to upload multiple files

```
 onSelectedFile(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    this.productForm.get('imagePath').setValue(file)
    console.log(file)
  }
```

typescript:

```
 productForm: FormGroup;
 public imagePath;
constructor(public productService: ProductService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {

    this.productForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      imagePath: ['']
   })
  }

  public onSelectedFileMultiple(event) {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const files = event.target.files;
      this.productForm.get('imagePath').setValue(files);
      console.log(files)
    }
  }
public onProductSubmit(): any {

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('imagePath', this.productForm.get('imagePath').value);
    //checking value of imagePath after appending to formData
    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(pair[0] + ': ' + pair[1]);  //returning value as imagePath: [object FileList]
    }

   this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:4000/api/v1' + '/post-product', formData);
```

HTML:

```
<form fxLayout="row wrap" [formGroup]="productForm" (ngSubmit)="onProductSubmit()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="100" class="px-1" ngClass.sm="mt-1" ngClass.xs="mt-1" method="post">
              <label>Upload Image</label>
              <mat-form-field class="w-100 form-group">
              <ngx-mat-file-input multiple type="file" formControlName="imagePath" name="imagePath" placeholder="PDF file only" (change)="onSelectedFileMultiple($event)" [accept]="'application/x-zip-compressed,image/*'"></ngx-mat-file-input>
              <mat-icon class="btn-project" mat-raised-button color="accent">folder</mat-icon>
            </mat-form-field>
            </div>
<div class="button-wrap" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="100" class="px-1" ngClass.sm="mt-1" ngClass.xs="mt-1">
              <button class="btn-project" mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit">Post Product</button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: The database is so many layers away from what you have here. Check your network tab. Look at the request.

Comment: it's coming as ```Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imagePath"

[object FileList]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on `onSelectedFileMultiple($event)` that it only appends a single value for imagePath to the formData. What could be done is to just loop through the files array and append every file in that array to the formData

```
public onProductSubmit(): any {

    const formData = new FormData();
    files.forEach(file => {
       formData.append('imagePath[]', file);
    })

   this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:4000/api/v1' + '/post-product', formData);
}
```